# CSS have index.php in url

Tags: php, css, joomla1.5

My website have increased visitor so I decide to change server to increase capacity. I use joomla 1.5 with Ja Teline IV template.

When I change server all css have background image with relative path show like this:

Original path:

```
url('fake-path/images/arrow-3.png')
```

Path in css cache:

```
url('/index.php/fake-path/images/arrow-3.png')
```

It have index.php in path.

How can i solve this problem? and what's cause from?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the forward slash before the **index.php* like so:

```
background: url('index.php/fake-path/images/arrow-3.png');
```

else use relative path like so:

```
background: url('../images/arrow-3.png');
```

Note that when using the second option, don't forget to change the path that applies to you.